# MSI netbook refuses to connect to home wireless network with Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, wireless-networking, netbook

I'm trying to connect my girlfriend's MSI netbook to the wireless network in my house, and failing repeatedly. It's not a hardware issue, b/c it connects to other networks successfully, and, it's not a network issue, because I have another mac and linux laptops that have no problem detecting and connecting to the same network.

When I open windows' network connections box, I can see the network available, and when I try to connect to it (using a password), I get a "network no longer in range.." error (the router is 2 ft away). This has been the case for the past 6 months, and I'm about to give up. I've reset the router, erased all saved network preferences and pretty much all I could think of short of re-installing XP. Any idea what else could be done? thanks.

Comment: Have you tried installing the newest driver for the wireless card? You should identify the card, (instructions here http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-xp/help/networking/install-wireless-network-adapter), then do a google search for a new driver under windows. If it is an oldish bug, they may have corrected it in the meantime

Answer (score 1):

I had what may be the same problem with an hp laptop.
compared settings to a working laptop and discoverwed psk2 was enabled on the working side (router and laptop) MS had a  [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&familyid=662BB74D-E7C1-48D6-95EE-1459234F4483&displaylang=en) to add that to machines that didn't have it.
Worked for me after a reboot

Answer (score 0):

Some network cards have difficulty with the router wpa/wpa2 setting. Set the encryption to WPA and try connecting again. Also make sure the network name is removed from remembered networks.